# Charset for exporting from SQL developer

Tags: character-encoding, oracle-sqldeveloper

When exporting from Oracle SQL Developer I've been mostly using 'Macroman', but this causes some problems when I further want to manipulate the data with Python, or when I import the CSV-files into Excel. Since some of the characters are Norwegian characters and special signs I often have to replace these by find-replace or other tedious methods. I have tried choosing both 'unicode' and 'utf-8' which I normally tend to prefer, but without any good effect. In python I end up with signs such as: '\xc3\xb8r', and in Excel '¢'.

Is there a good rule of thumb to get this right? What encoding is the most ubiquitous, and what works best with SQL Developer?

Comment: Hello, it is not clear what you are exporting from an Oracle SQL Developer. Are you exporting a database? What is NATIONAL CHARACTER SET of the Oracle installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem what not so much in SQL Developer, but in Excel. I ended up using SQL Developer to export the dataset using UTF-8, and then transforming it into excel using Google Refine.